# Difference between two times (without date) in PHP

Tags: php, time, difference

I know there are a lot same kind problems but nothing do what I need.

I have two times in the form of H.MM (3.25 - thats not 3:25, its 3:15) or HH.MM (22.75 - so its 22:45).

I need to calculate the difference between starttime and endtime in hours. And i don't have date.

My times are (so you can check):

1. 15.25 -> 23.75
2. 10.0 -> 22.0
3. 22.5 -> 8.0
4. 20.0 -> 10.0
5. 9.0 -> 17.0
6. 23.0 -> 6.0

My head is on fire already.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: The problem you're going to run into is it is not possible to know if 15.25 to 18.25 is 3.0 or 27.0, unless you cannot exceed a max number of hours (e.g., 24 or lower). Also, the easiest way is to shim a date for the first and offset from that. What date you use for that irrelevant.

Comment: Your specific problem might require some more constraints. For example, the difference between 11pm and 6am is _different_ when 6am is on the _following_ day, as opposed to _earlier_ that day.

Comment: Yes. Thats the problem...changing day.

If bigger nr is second one, then there is daychange. So 15.25 to 18.25 is 3.0 .

Comment: You mean if the *first* number is bigger than the *second* number, then the second number is the following day?

Comment: So it is. There is one problem more. 24.0 is same as 0.0 or 24:00 = 00:00.

Correct one: If smaller nr is second one*

Comment: In my list there is no such kind of time but that code need to work with every input.

Comment: You have an answer; why aren't you paying any attention to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$times = array(
    array(15.25,23.75),
    array(10.0,22.0),
    array(22.5,8.0),
    array(20.0,10.0),
    array(9.0,17.0),
    array(23.0,6.0),
);

foreach($times as $time) {

    $end = $time[1];

    if($time[1] < $time[0]) {
        $end += 24;
    }

    $diff = $end - $time[0];
    $hours = floor($diff);
    $minutes = ($diff - $hours) * 60;

    if(strlen($minutes) < 2)
        $minutes .= '0';

    print $time[0] . ' -> ' . $time[1] 
    . " $hours:$minutes\n";
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/hvlQuv)

Comment: I need to modify it a little bit but very very big thank you.

Comment: Haha. I just needed that:

if($time[1] < $time[0]) {
        $end += 24;
    }